# Can I reset skills in KF2?

Tags: killing-floor-2

In Killing Floor 2 the perk system works differently, when you hit level 5 you seem to have options as to what you want as a bonus for each perk.   Can you reset these at anytime or does it stay with you until you gain another five levels in that perk?

I'm currently level 3 (nearly 4) Commando, so I'd like to know if it isn't a reversible decision.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can simply pick bonuses any time in the menu or before starting a game. So yes, it is reversible. Once you reach Level 5, you can simply choose either bonus, and change at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to the Perks menu, then click on Configure:

[image]

Mouse over the skill you want. A red box should outline the desired choice:

[image]

Click to confirm.  Your new skill has been set!

[image]